# SQL Date Filter: Return results when start date = end date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, between

:startDate and :endDate are given value from html input and passed as parameters with AJAX. I want to return notifications BETWEEN :startDate and :endDate, but also return a notification if startDate is equal to endDate.(A user enters the same date for both input boxes).

```
SELECT  name, FK_userID, subject, messageText, recipients, 
        CONVERT     (varchar, date) as date 
        FROM        notifications
        LEFT JOIN   users ON users.userID = 
                    notifications.FK_userID
        WHERE       date
        BETWEEN     :startDate AND :endDate
        OR          CONVERT (datetime, date) = :startDate
        ORDER BY    CONVERT (datetime, date, 100) desc
```

The OR statement breaks the first condition. The query works with just the BETWEEN statement. If a user inputs the same date value for startDate and endDate, I would expect the OR part of the query to return any notifications that have the same date value as was entered into both input boxes.
Expected output would look like:
startDate = 10/10/2020
endDate = 10/10/2020

returns any notifications with the date value 10/10/2020

Comment: So what about your query isn't working? Consider showing some sample data and expected results as formatted text.

Comment: What is the datatype of `date`? The `BETWEEN` is inclusive - values that fall on either of the expressions in the `BETWEEN` will already be included.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You wrote *The query works with just the BETWEEN statement*, which means that you don't need anything beyond that, but you've added the `CONVERT` statement that breaks things. Remove the `CONVERT` and you've answered your own question.

Comment: The datatype of date is datetime. If a user input 10/20/2020 for both the startDate and endDate, any row with the date 10/20/2020 will not be returned, because it is not between those values. I am trying to include results if startDate and endDate are equal, and there is a row with that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying:

> The query works with just the BETWEEN statement.

and this is true, because [BETWEEN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/between-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) has inclusive range meaning that

```
date BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate
```

is the same as:

```
date >= :startDate AND date <= :endDate
```

and that's why there is no need by your `OR` condition:

```
OR CONVERT (datetime, date) = :startDate
```